# Working with large files - preventing Out of Memory errors?

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I'm on Windows 7 Professional x86.

I'm working with some proprietary files that are relatively large in size (~900 MB compressed, 1.5 GB uncompressed).

This program is also proprietary and the only one that will work with the file format that I'm trying to use, so I can't really choose anything else. It's a .NET application if that makes any difference.

Now here's the problem: the way the program works is very poor. It loads the compressed file, and keeps a handle on it. Then uncompresses it and keeps that in application memory. Then if I want to save the changes I've made, I have to save a new copy of the file, which requires compressing it and saving to disk.

Saving the file is the problem here - I basically have an application trying to store 3 or 4 copies of this humungous 1.5 GB file in memory, and only 4 GB of RAM on my system. As a result, it crashes about 1/4 of the way through the saving process with System Out of Memory exception.

- Increasing the size of the page file hasn't changed anything, though I will admit I am not too keen on how paging files work.
- I don't have access to any machines with more RAM to perform the operation.
- I'm on a laptop (which will be replaced in the coming months) so I don't want to buy/install more RAM.
- I don't really want to reformat to x64, and I'm not sure if that would help anything given that I only have 4 GB of RAM.

Speed is not an issue here; I just want the thing to have enough memory to complete successfully.

Note that I have no idea what the problem actually is. I don't know if it's because I don't have enough RAM, or because Windows only gives applications a limited amount of memory, or because my page file is too small or anything.

Does anybody have any ideas on what the problem may be and how I can alleviate it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that unless the program asks for more memory, windows will only give it 2GB of memory to play with. This problem can be "fixed" by making the application large address aware but this is best done though recompilation of the file (It *might* be possible to change the header directly, but this would be a terrible idea, and probably won't work).

If you do not know the programmer/s that can fix this, there is nothing you can do, sorry.